# How to deal with infinity in a 2D matrix

Tags: css, matrix, svg, transform

I'm writing an algorithm that parses and multiply 2D transform commands as found in SVG or CSS, e.g. `translate(30px, 40px) rotate(45deg) scale(2) skewX(-45deg)`

Each command individually and their product are equivalent to a 2d matrix of the form `[a, b, c, d, tx, ty]`. It works relatively well, until I try to use the command `skewX(∓90deg)`, which is equivalent to `[1, 0, Infinity, 1, 0, 0]`. When I try to multiply that with another transform, the matrix product often contains a `0 * Infinity` operation, which results in `NaN` in JS, and this NaN value skrews up with following mathematical operations and rendering.

The solution I've adopted so far is to wrap potential `0 * Infinity` operations with `( 0 * Infinity || 0 )`, so that the result is 0. I know this is mathematically wrong but it seems to work, so far.

Is there a cleaner and more systematic approach to dealing with `Infinity` in a 2d Matrix, or even just dealing with the annoying `skewX(∓90deg)`?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should throw a RANGE_ERR if you're parsing it in a DOM context. If you're parsing markup then [stop parsing the transform](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/implnote.html#ErrorProcessing) at that point.

Comment: This is not the answer I expected but it actually makes sense. Thanks!